# Vim Plugin limelight not working with vim in the gnome terminal

Tags: vim, gnome-terminal, vim-plugins

all. I am using the gnome-terminal 3.26.1 and vim 8.0.1176.
Installing Limelight  worked, but when i want to start it, i get the error message in the *gnome-terminal*

> Unsupported Terminal. Sorry

Limelight works on terminals that support 256 colors. As far as i know *gnome-terminal* supports that many colors.

When i use vim inside xfce4-terminal Limelight is working. 
Happy for any suggestions. Thanks in advance!
I use zsh 5.4 by the way

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM`? Try `gnome-256color` or `xterm-256color`.

Comment: Hello Ingo. TERM is set to xterm-256color. If i change to gnome-256-color i can use limelight also in gnome-shell yay (:

Comment: Ah nice! I've turned it into a proper answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problems usually hint at a wrong value of `TERM`.

Apparently, the correct value is `gnome-256color`. I don't know why `xterm-256color` doesn't work, too. That's the new default (at least in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with Gnome Terminal 3.18.3).